# Formatting from Notepad++ to Notepad alignment and indentation not working

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I am using `Notepad++` for coding while my client is using `Notepad`. When they opened my code in `Notepad` the formatting is note getting correctly. I had read some article which says that there is an option like the following in `Notepad++`

[image: Refer image]

But after that in notepad it needs to be pasted using `Edit>Special Paste` . In normal Notepad `Edit>Special Paste` option is not available. How can I overcome this issue?  Or please suggest a free editor, in which alignment and indentation will not go even if I open on Notepad. Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: You "read some article". Which article? You should not need to export anything. You may find that experimenting with Notepad++'s menu => **EDIT** => **EOL Conversion** provides what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notepad is a *text* editor, it understands nothing about things like HTML or RTF.

I believe that *Wordpad* may read RTF (as would Word presumably) and certainly you can use a web browser to view HTML but, since you're *creating* text in Notepad++, I'm not sure what you hope to gain.

If your intent is to show the syntax colouring that you get in Notepad++, WordPad/WebBrowser would allow your client to *view* it, but editing would be another issue.

If the issue is simply to do with indentation, it will probably have to do with the mixed use of tabs and/or spaces. You can change Notepad++ to use spaces in lieu of tabs, in `Settings | Preferences | Tab settings`. Once spaces are used everywhere, Notepad should be able to render the indentation just fine.

Comment: When the formatted code which was created using Notepad++ opening in Notepad it is not working . How can I overcome that. Hope now you got my point.

Comment: @Santhucool, "is not working" could do with some explanation. What is the actual problem when you open it in Notepad?

Comment: @paxdiablo I mean alignment and intentation not working. I do not want any colouring stuff in Notpad. Or please suggest a free editor, in which alignment and indentation will not go even if I open on Notepad.